# if-logic elimination from map call

Tags: java, if-statement, vavr

I often see in vavr-based code:

```
...
.map(x -> {
   if (someCondition(x)) {
      return doWith(x);
   } else {
     return x;
   }
})
...
```

Is there any way to eliminate this logic from `map` call using some constructs? I find this `if` condition awkward.

Answer (score 4):

Using the ternary conditional expression may look better:

```
.map(x -> someCondition(x) ? doWith(x) : x)
```

Comment: Actually, this changes nothing. Whether it's ternary of `if` statement doesn't matter. But thanks for the idea.

Comment: @Opal it reduces the length of the code. It eliminates the need to use curly braces and return statement. Hence I'd say it's less awkward than using `if`.

Comment: Yes, I see it, however this is not what I was looking for. What I'm looking for is some vavr or functional construct I don't know about. Yet ;)

Comment: What I'm looking for is a concept while what you suggested is just syntax.

Comment: @Opal I guess you were hoping for a Stream method such as `mapIf(Predicate,Function)`, but it doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, it does not exist. That's why I'm asking how to replace it.

Answer (score 3):

My idea would be to wrap x with optional

```
   .map(x -> Optional.ofNullable(x)
            .filter(this::someCondition)
            .map(this::doWith)
            .orElse(x))
```

And this returns `Optional<X>` so U need to handle it properly somewhere else

Comment: While this works, this is overkill, and more importantly, it doesn't carry the intention. Your code makes it hard to understand you want to conditionally transform the element. The ternary operator or if-else statement is more expressive.

Comment: of course, for some it might be an overkill, but that is just mine/another approach to replace if-statement

Answer (score 2):

Either use the ternary operator if the conditions do not contain any logic or very little

```
.map(x -> someCondition(x) ? doWith(x) : x)
```

Or extract the logic within the map in a method

```
.map(ClassName::myXTreatmentMethod)
// or
.map(this::myXTreatmentMethod)
```

With `myXTreatmentMethod` being

```
public X_Type myXTreatmentMethod(X_Type x) {
    if (someCondition(x)) {
        // some logic
        return doWith(x);
    }
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `case-match` like the following:

```
Iterator.range(0, 10)
        .map(index -> Match(index).of(
            Case($(n -> n % 2 == 0), "even"),
            Case($(), "odd")
        ))
```